# cutting string into parts with npos

Tags: c++

I was practicing about **cutting a string into parts**, and I wrote these codes.

```cpp
string a = "12/1322.39102";
int current = 0;
int next;

while (true)
{
    next = a.find_first_of("/.", current);

    if (next != current)
    {
        cout << "c = " << current << endl;
        cout << "n - c = " << next-current << endl;
        string tmp = a.substr(current, next-current);

        if (tmp.size())
            cout << tmp << endl;
    }

    if (next == string::npos)
        break;

    current = next + 1;
}
```

I was confused because if `find_first_of` cannot find any character (i.e. '/' and '.'), it'll return `npos`, or return -1.

In that case, I think it'll not output the last number 39102 because next-current equal -9.

Another question is, what's the difference between `npos` and `end()` (used in vector or map) ?

Comment: btw, codes mainly refer to [here](http://justimchung.blogspot.com/2018/03/c.html)

Comment: Does this compile? As far as I remember std::find_first_of expects iterators as input. Please check.

Comment: @ArminMontigny [`std::find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of) does take iterators, but [`std::basic_string::find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) takes string/char and optionally a starting position.

Comment: npos is a size_t type whereas end is an iterator.

Comment: I just wonder when `std::find_first_of` cannot find any character matched in string, it'll return `string::npos`, but it'll make `next-current` to be a negative integer, then how does `substr()` works?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen. Sorry, You are right. With std::string takes other parameters. Sorry again

Comment: And [this](https://ideone.com/AC4MBB) is the result after I run this code, hope it helps, thanks.

Comment: `if (next == string::npos)` should be the first check after your search.

Comment: @JstMonika You're right, my answer was invalid. Removed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Aside of the very good point Yksisarvinen made, right now you first try to exploit the result, before checking if there is any valid result. In your code `next ==string::npos` is true, and nothing inside the first if will behave as expected.

The absolute first check you should make when searching, whichever technique you use (find, regex, homemade code) is ***did we find anything ?*** `if (next == string::npos)` should be the first thing after find...

Comment: Can I just move this check below the output?
I think `if (next == string::npos)` is meant to check if there has any other character between to substring, which means it will has another output after `next == string::npos` is true.
This is my [code](https://ideone.com/2gOYBc), the previous one is refer to the web, sorry for that.

Comment: no you can't. `next != current` will be true if the string is non empty and there is no match.